# Design a circuit in Ltspice based on the input and output

Tags: voltage-regulator, rectifier, voltage-clipping

I need to design a circuit that takes a sinusoidal input with peak of 8V and generate an output such that the positive peaks remain the same and the negative peaks get inverted and have a peak of 4V.
[image]

Comment: You need to ask a question.

Answer (score 1):

Look up "ideal rectifiers" or "precision rectifiers" made with op-amps.

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_rectifier#:~:text=The%20precision%20rectifier%2C%20also%20known,an%20ideal%20diode%20and%20rectifier.&text=The%20op%2Damp%2Dbased%20precision,based%20active%20rectification%20ideal%20diode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_rectifier#:%7E:text=The%20precision%20rectifier%2C%20also%20known,an%20ideal%20diode%20and%20rectifier.&text=The%20op%2Damp%2Dbased%20precision,based%20active%20rectification%20ideal%20diode).

Apply the input to two ideal rectifiers of opposite polarities, and them mix the results with a third op amp, set to voltage divide one of the inputs by 50%. The result should be what you are looking for.